# Gaussian with mean equal to another random variable equal to that random variable plus noise - proof?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Consider a Gaussian whose mean is the realization of another random variable: $p(x|y) = N(x; y, 1)$. I believe this is equivalent to saying $X \sim Y + N(0, 1)$.

Intuitively, this makes sense. If we first sample from Y and then choose a point near that by centering a Gaussian on it, it seems sensible that this is equivalent to choosing Y and then adding some noise.

In python, I tried simulating this by sampling many points from a triangular distribution (y) and then either adding standard normal noise to it ($x_2$) or using it as the mean of another normal distribution, and then sampling form that ($x$). As you can see, the histograms indicate that they are indeed equivalent.

[image]

However, I am having trouble seeing how to prove this statement. Does anybody have guidance or a resource that proves this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
     p_X(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p_Y(y)p_{X|Y}(x|y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p_Y(y)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-y)^2}dy \\&=(p_Y*\mathcal{N})(x)
\end{align}

where $*$ denotes the convolution, and $\mathcal{N}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$. Therefore, since in general $Z+W=U\iff p_U(u)=(p_Z*p_W)(u)$, we have that $X=N(0,1)+Y$.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I just figured out that I need to incorporate convolutions - it became a lot simpler when I used Desmos to just plot everything out. Thanks again! 

Answer (score 1):

In general for the normal distribution, if $Z\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, then $X = Z+\mu ~ \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

To see this, note the Characteristic Function:
$E[e^{i t Z}] = e^{- \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t^2}$.
So
$E[e^{i t X}] = E[e^{i t (\mu + Z)}] = e^{i t \mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t^2}$,
which is the characteristic function for $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

With the same approach you can also prove that if $Y\sim N(0,1)$, then $\mu + \sigma Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. (Exercise.)

Comment: I'm a bit confused - in your particular example you consider adding a fixed scalar to the random variable Z. In my case, the value being added is another random variable (Y) which would imply that (according to your notation) $X = Z + y \sim N(y, \sigma^2$ conditioned on y, so $P(X=x) = \int N(y, \sigma^2)*P(Y=y)dy$, no?

Comment: Sure, you can do it conditionally on a random variable $Y$ if you want: $E[e^{it(Y+Z)}|Y] = e^{itY - \frac12 \sigma^2 t^2}$. Doesn't really change things much.